# how to load the javascript in android webView

Tags: android

i have the two java script files of my web service..and it will display the bar charts in web view...but i'm unable to get that....this is the code which i used

```
             String url="http://************/getchart.php?   id="+id+"&sessionid=*********";
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/jquery.js");
            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/jscharts.js");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:$(document).ready(function() {setChart();});");
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            /*view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/jquery.js");
            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/jscharts.js");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:$(document).ready(function() {setChart();});");*/

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    });
    webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are You Sure add this ...

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: but attach your `.js` file in html page

Answer (score 0):

Create a new HTML page `charts.html` in assets folder:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/jscharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){setChart();});"
</script>
```

Then load it with

```
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/charts.html");
```

If you need some parameters from Activity (maybe `id`) inside your javascripts, take a look at [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)